# How to Set Leaflet Map's Zoom to Show All Markers in React Leaflet?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, leaflet, react-leaflet

I have a React Leaflet map that needs to change its center and zoom when given a set of markers. The zoom should be changed such that all the markers are visible.

This change of view is currently being attempted using the function `ChangeView`.

Using my code below, I am able to move the map view, but not able to let the map fit to the bounds. Running the code gives the error:

> Error: Bounds are not valid.

on the line

```
map.fitBounds(markerBounds)
```

What can we do? Thanks!

```
import L, { LatLng, latLngBounds, FeatureGroup } from 'leaflet';
import React from 'react';
import { MapContainer, TileLayer, Marker, Popup, useMap } from 'react-leaflet';
import MarkerClusterGroup from 'react-leaflet-markercluster';

import { LatLon, MapMarker } from '../../common/types';
import { config } from '../../config';

interface IProps {
    markers: MapMarker[];
    searchCenter: LatLon;
}

interface IChangeView {
    center: LatLon;
    markers: MapMarker[];
}

function ChangeView({ center, markers }: IChangeView) {
    const map = useMap();
    map.setView({lng: center.lon, lat: center.lat}, DEFAULT_ZOOM);
    
    let markerBounds = latLngBounds([]);
    markers.forEach(marker => {
        markerBounds.extend([marker.lat, marker.lon])
    })
    map.fitBounds(markerBounds)   // <===== Error: Bounds are not valid.
    return null;
}


export function MapView({markers, searchCenter}: IProps): JSX.Element {
    
    return (
        <MapContainer
            center={[searchCenter.lat, searchCenter.lon]}
            zoom=14
            style={{ width:'100%', height:'100vh' }}
            className='markercluster-map'
        >
            <ChangeView center={searchCenter} markers={markers} />
            <TileLayer 
                url={`https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/mapbox/streets-v11/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token=${config.api.mapbox}`}
            />
            <MarkerClusterGroup>
                {
                    markers.map((marker, index) => (
                        <Marker 
                            position={[marker.lat, marker.lon]} 
                            key={index}
                        />
                    ))
                }
            </MarkerClusterGroup>
        </MapContainer>
    )
}
```

---

Also tried using `FeatureGroup` instead of `latLngBounds`, but it gave the exact same error

> Error: Bounds are not valid

```
    let group = new FeatureGroup();
    markers.forEach(marker => {
        L.marker([marker.lat, marker.lon]).addTo(group);
    })
    map.fitBounds(group.getBounds());
```

Comment: Can you do a `console.log(markerBounds)` right before `map.fitBounds(markerBounds)`?  What does that give?  Also, what does your `markers` array look like?  Is there always values, or is it sometimes empty?

Comment: @SethLutske It's sometimes empty, and this is the problem. Thanks!

Comment: Do you only ever get this error when the markers array is empty?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `markers` array is empty, or `null`, the bounds you create will not have `._southWest` and `._northEast` properties, and that error will throw.  Just make the `fitBounds` statement conditional on there being markers in the array:

```js
if (markers.length && markers.length > 0){
  markers.forEach(marker => {
    markerBounds.extend([marker.lat, marker.lon])
  })
  map.fitBounds(markerBounds)
}
```

Or even just a quick one liner:

```js
markerBounds.isValid() && map.fitBounds(markerBounds)
```