# Show All Markers in React Leaflet in One View

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet

How to set Leaflet map zoom to show all markers in React Leaflet? I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65878831/how-to-set-leaflet-maps-zoom-to-show-all-markers-in-react-leaflet), but it's typescript.

```js
import _ from "lodash";
import "leaflet/dist/leaflet.css";
import { MapContainer, TileLayer, Marker } from "react-leaflet";
import { markerBlack } from "assets/js/marker";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

function Map() {
    const [systems, setSystems] = useState([]);

    const getSystems = () => {
        axios("get", "/api/systems/", {}).then((response) => {
            if (response.status === 200) {
                if (response.data.status === 200) {
                    setSystems(response.data.systems);
                }
            }
        });
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        getSystems();
    }, []);

    return (
        <MapContainer center={[35.7012, 51.35191]} zoom={13} scrollWheelZoom={false} style={{ width: "100%", height: "400px" }}>
            <TileLayer url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png" />
            {Object.keys(systems).map((key) => (
                <Marker key={_.uniqueId()} position={[systems[key].latitude, systems[key].longitude]} icon={markerBlack} />
            ))}
        </MapContainer>
    );
}

export default Map;
```

It shows markers ok, but I want to show all in one view.

react: 17.0.2

react-leaflet: 3.2.5

leaflet: 1.9.2

Comment: All you have to do is add all markers to the featuregroup and then set this layer using map.fitBounds on the map, here you have my solution [matching-all-markers-to-the-map-view](https://tomik23.github.io/react-leaflet-examples/#/matching-all-markers-to-the-map-view)

Comment: @GrzegorzT. I test it and work ok, please answer the question